# Bolt cms and Ckeditor

Tags: php, wysiwyg, bolt-cms

How to add select FontSize and Font Family in Ckeditor Bolt cms.

[The method](https://docs.bolt.cm/contenttypes-and-records), described here does not work

Used bolt cms version cms 2.2

Comment: What about it "doesn't work"? What have you tried? What about what you tried "didn't work"? What would constitute a "working" state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem myself. Downloaded the full version of the editor and plugged my config.js instead of that by default. )))

Now you can do with the editor all you want (for example to connect any plugins).